# Is A* reasonable to use for 2D array pathfinding in C?

Tags: c, arrays, path-finding, a-star

I need my C program to be able to travel around a board. The board is represented by a 2D int array (where 0 and 7 are empty squares and everything else is an obstacle). The cost to move from one square to another is always the same but it should not move diagonally.

I've been looking up A* but it's confusing and every single example I could find is with C++ or Java so I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible on C.

That and if it's the best algorithm to use for it.

Edit: The board is either 24x25 or 25x24 I can't remember which

Comment: Is the board large? Very? How much?

Comment: Can you show us what your board looks like?  Are you reading it in from a file and then storing it in a 2D array?

Comment: So are you doing pathing around the board? What kind of "travel" are you doing? Does the board ever change?

Comment: @nneonneo I'm assuming he's given a start point and an end point with a static board layout.

Comment: The board does change sometimes but not majorly so. They will have to navigate around other players. And travel is moving from one space to another that's not next to them.

Comment: Oh and I'm not reading it from a file I'm making it in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your board is small, you can use a [breadth-first search (BFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) doing a complete search for the best path. I think that the performance will be comparable if not better than A* algorithm.

The algorithm is simpler than A* and there are many implementations in C over the internet. Here is an example of a BFS transversal on a grid:

[image: An illustration of a BFS transversal on a grid. If all squares are reachable, the distances from center are those indicated.]

To get the path you can save a matrix (for example a 2d-array of char -- lets name it `parent`) where `parent[x][y]` is for example (0 - if you reach that square from left, 1 - right, 2 - up, 3 - down). For example, if you're visiting the square with coords (4,6) and will put the (5,6) on the queue, you do  `parent[5][6] = 2` because (5,6) came from the row above (4,6). So to retrieve the full path you can pick the destination node and save the `parents` coordinates until you reach the source square.

Now it is up to you think about and figure how you can implement it :)

Comment: How would that work for path finding? Would I look at all 4 squares around the start, and then keep going from there? Oh and how will it remember the path?

Comment: @RobertZ: yes, BFS is a graph search algorithm that can be used in your problem. It works by visiting all the neighbors from a node (square in your case). Everytime you visit a node, you put all neighbors of it on a queue. I recommend you to read the Wikipedia article that I put on my answer, you'll find out that BFS guarantee some properties useful in your problem (like the first time you reach a square, it will be the shortest path from the start point to that square).

Comment: That only leaves the problem of how I will remember the path it took to get there, or will I need to do multiple BFS's

Comment: Nope. You can save a matrix called `parent` for example. More details in the answer above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you mean another 2d board, or is matrix a data type I don't know about.

Comment: @RobertZ instead of marking cells visited, you can assign them the step number when they were visited (exactly as in the picture), then to reconstruct a shortest path you simply need to step back from each `n` to any of `n-1` until you reach `0`.

Comment: Wait never mind I saw the other paragraph explaining it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Indeed the @hamstergene's solution is way more elegant than mine. It saves space and logic :). +1 for you!

Comment: I'd have to use negative numbers, because I'm using those numbers to represent obstacles too. Then I guess I'll have to mark them with something else to indicate their part of the path. I'll figure it out. Thanks both of you.

Comment: A* is really not that much more complicated than BFS; just use a priority-queue rather than a queue, and add a heuristic to order it by.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes, A* is very straightforward but in this case I think it would be slower than BFS because the board size is very small.